# Class and Generic in Java

Tags: java

There is this function

```
Transformers.aliasToBean(RoomInfoDTO.class);
```

Now I would to use the above function in my generic method. How do I pass the `class` into the method and use it ?

I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
passThis(PurchaseHistoryDTO.class);
....

function passThis(Class<?> passedClass){

Transformers.aliasToBean(passedClass.getClass());

}
```

Somehow the function takes the class as `class java.lang.Class`.

Comment: Don't call `getClass()`, just pass the `Class`.

Comment: Well, `passedClass` is instance of `Class` so `getClass()` should return `class java.lang.Class`. Nothing abnormal here. Why do you call `getClass()` on the first place?

Comment: @Pshemo the point is he didn't know that, i can assume he was caling get class because he didn't know how else to do it or he didn't know he didn't actually have to do anything.

Comment: @SeanF Yes, you are right, but I wanted to hear that from OP and make him to think about it a little and ask himself "...why do I call `getClass()` here? I already have Class that represents my type."

Comment: @Pshemo, I did add the `getClass()` because I assume it would be equivalent with `.class`. Anyway thank you guys for the explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass the argument directly without calling `getClass` on it. `passedClass` is a Class object, so calling `getClass` on it will obviously return `java.lang.Class`. Just do:

```
function passThis(Class<?> passedClass){

     Transformers.aliasToBean(passedClass); //just pass the class, not the class's class

}
```

Also, I'm assuming that "function" is shorthand/psuedocode; that won't compile in java. substitute it with a return type, probably `void`.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in the class, so you can operate on it directly.

```
void passThis(Class<?> passedClass) {

  Transformers.aliasToBean(passedClass);

}
```

You also don't say `function` in Java. You might be thinking of JavaScript.

On another note, there is basically no point to using a generic class as you have it in your example. Passing in simply `(Class passedClass)` would work just as well.

So the question is why you went the generics route. It could be you want something more like this:

```
<T> T passThis(Class<T> passedClass){

        return Transformers.aliasToBean(passedClass);

}
```

Just depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

As you already passed class object `PurchaseHistoryDTO.class` in

```
Class<?> passedClass argument,
```

just pass "**passedClass** in the method like :

```
Transformers.aliasToBean(passedClass);
```

It should work.